# How to get Eclipse dark Java theme for Netbeans?

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, themes

I'm looking for this and I can't find it.

Eclipse dark theme for Java is very usable for me but I'm trying to set on Netbeans and I don't know how and I can't find how do it.

Thanks for help.

EDIT: This is [Eclipse dark theme for Java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkHEM.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/21042861/2670892

Comment: I saw that but it's not the same thing...

Comment: IDEs have completely different ways of doing themes, you can't take a theme from one and use it on another. You have to use what the particular IDE offers.

Answer (score 1):

Tools->Options->Miscellaneous->Windows choose either Dark Metal or Dark Nimbus in the "Preferred look and feel" combo box. Then in Tools->Options->Fonts & Colors choose Norway Today in the "Profile" combo box. Restart NetBeans.
https://dzone.com/articles/new-netbeans-dark-laf

Comment: _Norway Today_ does not look like Eclipse Dark Theme at all.

Comment: @RousseauAlexandre please tell us which one looks like Eclipse Dark Theme.